# Convert Parent Class to child in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider this scenario,

I have two classes Student and HonorsStudent respectively.

```
class Student{
    String name;
    int roll;
    Student(String name, int roll){
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;        
   }
}
class HonorStudent extends Student{
    int honorid;
    HonorStudent(String name, int roll,int honorid){
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.honorid = honorid;        
   }
   HonorStudent(String name, int roll){
        this.name = name;
         this.roll = roll;
   }
}
```

Now, there might be scenarios in which I might want to convert a Student into an HonorStudent. Since downcasting is not allowed in this situation, I can't do this:

```
   Student s1 = new Student("abc",123);
   HonorStudent s = (HonorStudent)s1;
```

So the other way of doing this would be to define a method in HonorStudent which inputs a Student Object and returns a HonorStudent:

```
   public static HonorStudent convertToHonor(Student s){
       return new HonorStudent(s.name,s.roll);
   }
```

This is convenient if there are only two attributes(name, roll), but what if I have a lot of attributes say 50 ? In that case I would have to input each and every attribute into HonorStudent?

I strongly feel there might be an easier way to do this?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking if there is a more convenient way to do this. If we consider just copying parameters from one object to another then there is no another way to do this. There might be ways to work around the problem by having objects for groups of member fields or by automating it by code that can copy member fields with same name from object to another.

**Small fix**

But first, let's improve design a bit. Fields should not be duplicated like this between classes in a class hierarchy. So let's eliminate that duplication:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int roll;

    public Student(String name, int roll) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
}

public class HonorStudent extends Student {
    private int honorId;

    public HonorStudent(String name, int roll, int honorId) {
        super(name, roll);
        this.honorId = honorId;
    }

    public int getHonorId() {
        return honorId;
    }
}
```

**Copy constructor**

If there is really a need to copy objects then copy constructor can be useful. Creating a copy constructor will allow you to skip passing each member field only by one.

```
public Student(Student other) {
    this.name = other.name;
    this.roll = other.roll;
}
```

Then creating Student part of the HonorStudent becomes simpler

```
public HonorStudent(Student student, int honorId) {
    super(student);
    this.honorId = honorId;
}
```

**Design**

Now it is not common that objects change their type. So this is not a common thing to do. This is usually solved by different kind of design of classes. For example, `honorId` could be part of `Student` class because, I guess, student can gain this attribute or loose it. Behaviour related to honor can be in some other class that is attached to student class.

Reading about [behavioural design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) can be useful. Depending which pattern to choose will depend on the use case and the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Sorry I didn't notice the duplicate fields

Comment: @GopalaKrishnan Great. Feel free to accept the answer if that solved your problem :)